# Listing All Active Directory Groups

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

The following code lists some, but not all, Active Directory Groups. Why?

I am trying to list all security groups, distribution groups, computer groups etc.  Have I specified the wrong `objectClass`?

```
private static void ListGroups()
{
    DirectoryEntry objADAM = default(DirectoryEntry);
    DirectoryEntry objGroupEntry = default(DirectoryEntry);
    DirectorySearcher objSearchADAM = default(DirectorySearcher);
    SearchResultCollection objSearchResults = default(SearchResultCollection);
    SearchResult myResult=null;

    objADAM = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP);
    objADAM.RefreshCache();
    objSearchADAM = new DirectorySearcher(objADAM);
    objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
    objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll();

    // Enumerate groups 
    try
    {
        fileGroups.AutoFlush = true;
        if (objSearchResults.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (SearchResult objResult in objSearchResults)
            {
                myResult = objResult;
                objGroupEntry = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                Console.WriteLine(objGroupEntry.Name);
                fileGroups.WriteLine(objGroupEntry.Name.Substring(3));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No groups found");
        }  
    } 
    catch (PrincipalException e)
    {
        fileErrorLog.AutoFlush = true;
        fileErrorLog.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + myResult.Path);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20140830173256/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: I would encapsulate `PrincipalContext`, `GroupPrincipal`, and `PrincipalSearcher` in using blocks since they are disposable.

Answer (score 2):

Try filter "(objectcategory=group)"
Found solution [here](http://www.activedir.org/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/29/LDAP-tips-2-Searching-for-Groups.aspx)

Comment: Sorry Sergey, same result, not all groups listed.  Answer from marc_s seems to work (provided you are on .NET 3.5 or higher).

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("ldap://ldap.gaurangjadia.com", "scott", "tiger");

DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

SearchResultCollection results = dSearch.FindAll();

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++) {
    DirectoryEntry de = results[i].GetDirectoryEntry();

    //TODO with "de"
}
```

Comment: This did not give me the right results, but marc_s solution did.

Comment: Be careful with this as stated in [this blogpost](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html), the `GetDirectoryEntry()` will load **ALL** properties, including the ones you don't need

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
    public ArrayList GetAllGroupNames(string ipAddress, string ouPath)
    {
        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
        deSearch.SearchRoot = GetRootDirectoryEntry(ipAddress, ouPath);
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            ArrayList groupNames = new ArrayList();

            foreach (SearchResult group in results)
            {
                var entry = new DirectoryEntry(group.Path, UserName, Password);
                string shortName = entry.Name.Substring(3, entry.Name.Length - 3);
                groupNames.Add(shortName);
            }

            return groupNames;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ArrayList();
        }
    }

    private DirectoryEntry GetRootDirectoryEntry(string ipAddress, string domainPath, string username, string password)
    {
        var ldapPath = "LDAP://" + ipAddress + "/" + domainPath;
        return new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    }
```

Comment: Hi What is GetRootDirectoryEntry?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a set of results that is larger than 1000 items, you must set SizeLimit to its default value (zero) and set PageSize to a value that is less than or equal to 1000.

objSearchADAM.PageSize = 1000;

Answer (score 0):

you can get the all ad group details by the below powershell and if you want particular Name against of AD Group then write filter instead of *

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -properties * | Export-csv c:\csv\new.csv