# Get all the azure active directory cloud based group in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, azure-active-directory

I'm facing an issue and i didn't succeed to resolve it.
In my Azure AD, i have two source for the group: Windows server AD and Cloud (has it is say in Azure UI)

I try to get them in my app so i follow what it is said in this link :
[Listing All Active Directory Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474718/listing-all-active-directory-groups)

However doing this i only have the groups that are in Windows server AD and not those from Cloud and i don't understand why ?

Can you help me with this please ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can start from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/groups-overview. For Azure AD, all the data is available via MS Graph API. Also, is your AD synchronised to AAD? If you synchronise the groups from AD to AAD, you don't need to query on-prem AD at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @juunas
So there is no way to access all the AAD groups with a principal searcher ?
And yes my AD is synchronised to my AAD

Comment: No, since AAD has no LDAP endpoint. Microsoft Graph API only accepts HTTP calls. There is an SDK for it which helps quite a lot though: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/

Comment: Ok ! Thank you very much for your help :)